# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when indirectly accessing inherited member in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I don't know if this is still a bug inherent in Swift, or if I'm getting something wrong, but here goes.

I have a class for creating menus (like a main menu and an options menu) in an iOS app, coded in Swift.

```
public class GameMenuScreen {
    private var _labels: Dictionary<String, SKLabelNode>

    // Getter/Setter indirection
    internal var labels: Dictionary<String, SKLabelNode> {
        get {
            return self._labels
        }
    }

    ...
}

class MainMenu: GameMenuScreen {
    ...
}
```

My issue is that `labels` is inherited by `MainMenu`, but when I attempt to access `MainMenu.labels` in a method, it throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

My thinking is that because the call to `MainMenu.labels` is sent to `GameMenuScreen`, the return value is `GameMenuScreen._labels`, not `MainMenu._labels`, and because there is no instance of `GameMenuScreen`, accessing `GameMenuScreen._labels` accesses unallocated memory.

I'd like to know how I structure this such that any call to `labels` refers to `self._labels` and not `super._labels`.

Running Xcode 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you would access an instance of it as MainMenu().whatever.  You need the ().  Not sure if that is your problem without seeing the full code.   Can you post more?

Comment: I mean if you create an instance of MainMenu, say mm, then call mm.labels, I get an error. I should mention that when I initialise MainMenu, I use super.init(), and _labels is initialised to an empty dictionary. Thus, it should exist, but it doesn't...